# Parse is shutting down. Will it be maintained by someone?

Tags: parse-platform, backend, mbaas, back4app

Parse.com is shutting down. So developers what we gonna do?

It is doing to be maintained as a open source solution?

I have heard something about back4app by Facebook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the future, not programming (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )

Comment: It will be maintained by community, as it has been till now with Parse-Server. This is what an open source is.

Answer (score 2):

Parse has been open sourced here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform

Answer (score 0):

The parse.com is now open sourced as Parse Server, all environment that support  node.js and Python can run your own Parse server.

There are  a lot of alternatives or where to store your parse server like

- Amazon, Bluemix, Azure, Heroku, Ocean, Cloud Engine and more, but for all of then, you have to spend alot of money with Cloud service and MongoDB for Data base (mLab, MongoLab, Compose.IO or other)

If its very importante to continue your app, i will suggest you to use a hosting provider that support Node.js and mongoDB also phyton. I'm using www.a2hosting.com and my app is running perfectly. You can try to download and see the performance. www.angopapo.com (Android)

Hope that helps.